# What is the name of an intransitive but complete binary relation?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, graph-theory, terminology, order-theory

A transitive and incomplete binary relation is a "preorder".

A transitive and complete binary relation is a "weak order".

A transitive, antisymmetric, and complete binary relation is a "total order" or linear order.

What "order" is it if it is intransitive and complete?

(reflexivity is always assumed)

---

"Completeness" means "connexity" in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). It seems like that Wikipedia was recently edited to remove the nomenclature of "completeness"

---

Ok solution found: it is called a "majority relation". With an additional axiom of "asymmetry", it becomes a strict majority relation or a tournament graph.

Comment: Please define incomplete binary relation, vs. complete binary operation.  Do you mean every element is comparable, or not?

Comment: @amWhy Completeness: $\forall a,b,$ either $aRb$ or $bRa$. Also known as connexity.

Comment: I don't know of a standard name for such a relation, but in response to your specific question what "order" it is, I would not expect an intransitive relation to be called an "order" at all.

Comment: *(Turning my now-deleted answer into a comment:)* If we add the requirement that we never have $aRb$ and $bRa$ for distinct $a,b$, then we're essentially looking at a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Interesting! What is the name of axiom stating that "we never have $aRb$ and $bRa$ at the same time"? BTW I think your answer is fine because this axiom is commonly assumed, I guess.

Comment: @ChrisEagle From my limited knowledge, a binary relation on X is a subset of $X\times X$, which is a list of ordered pair. So any binary relation could be named as some sort of "order", I guess.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think your answer is correct. If $aRb$ and $bRa$, then we usually say that $a$ and $b$ are equivalent. It is not a "strict" tournament graph, or a strict majority relation (as discussed in the last paragraph of your wikipedia page), but it is still a (weak) majority relation. I did some searching. The condition you mentioned is called "asymmetry"